# Why do I get a "volume with software packages has been detected" dialog every time I log in?

Tags: package-management, login

[image: screenshot]

This comes up every time I login, how do I remove this or fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any USB/CD/partition mounted which might contain Ubuntu updates?

Comment: You don't have a Live CD or USB inserted,  do you?

Comment: @TomBrossman I have my hard drive and a cd

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because you have:

- An Ubuntu install CD (or Live-CD) in your CD drive
- or, an Ubuntu LiveUSB plugged into your computer

Please eject and remove all CDs and any USB drives, and then try starting your computer. The message should no longer appear.